# Subfolder multisite issue. Themes and plugin files 404

Tags: multisite, themes, css, 404-error, directory

I've set up a subfolder multisite.
Main site: https://cs-amx.org/
Subdomain site: https://cs-amx.org/chypre

You see the maintenance screen is well displayed on the main site, but not on the subdomain site.

All the themes and plugin files lead to a 404.

For example, cs-amx.org/chypre/wp-content/plugins/maintenance/load/style.css doesn't load.

But cs-amx.org/wp-content/plugins/maintenance/load/style.css works well.

The admin panel at cs-amx.org/chypre/wp-admin/ works, though.

Here's the content of the .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .htaccess looks fine. It is exactly like the one I have. Do you have any .htaccess files inside /wp-content/ or /wp-includes/ or one level up from the main site folder?

Also try deactivating all plugins.

I also found [this topic](https://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/css-not-rendering-on-multisite-subfolders) that seems to be for the same issue. From what I read, there was a situation caused by hosting security measure in which the .htaccess file was not used and it was needed to do changes in the apps/wordpress/conf/http-app.conf file. This is [the exact post](https://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/css-not-rendering-on-multisite-subfolders#post-742850) I am talking about.

Comment: The issue came from Ngninx. Thank you for your reply, it helped me fixing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar issue to you.

In my case, my server was running apache **and** nginx. Nginx was serving static files, which meant the .htaccess was ignored *for the stylesheets and js files* etc. All of the admin areas worked great.

I got in touch with my hosting company who were able to disable the nginx static file hosting and that immediately sorted the issue.

Comment: This is correct! The fact the file has a suffix of .js, .css results in the request being give to Nginx to fulfil from file system, except the file does not exist with the network site directory prefix. The file is actually delivered due to the 404 fallback being routed back to Apache, but the HTTP status is 404 causing the browser to not include the content of the requested file.